# A function $y$ satisfies the differential equation $y'=x^2y^2$. Find a formula for $y$ in the solution curve passing through $(1,1)$.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, curves, differential

A function $y$ satisfies the differential equation $y'=x^2y^2$.  Find a formula for $y$ in the solution curve passing through $(1,1)$.

---

How would I set up an equation?  How should I start?  Thank you.

Comment: The de is seperable $\frac{d}{dx}(-\frac{1}{y})=\frac{y'}{y^2}=x^2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This DE is separable. Another way of writing "passing through point (1,1)" is $y(1)=1$. As the DE is separable, we can integrate
$$\int\frac{dy}{y^2}=\int x^2dx$$
to obtain
$$-\frac{1}{y}=\frac{1}{3}x^3+c$$
where $c$ is the constant of integration. Now apply the condition $y(1)=1$ to obtain the constant.
$$-1=\frac{1}{3}+c\implies c=-\frac{4}{3}$$
So the solution is
$$y=\frac{3}{4-x^3}$$